# How to get the value of attribute instead of an [Object object] ? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, object, selectors-api, getattribute

I always get `[Object object]` or are creating a conflict no matter how hard I try. (I tried a couple of other variants.) ;(

```js
var $ = function(selector){

  var x; 
  var obj = {
  
    myLib(selector){
      return x || document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    },
    
    cl(selector){
      x = [x[0].closest(selector)];
      return this;
    },    
      
    attr(s,v){
      s&&v ? x.forEach(y=>{y.setAttribute(s,v);})
           : x = [x[0].getAttribute(s)]; x.value; // what is wrong here ?
      return this;
    },
      
  };
        
  x = obj.myLib(selector);
  return obj;
  
};

var wtf = $('.kilo').cl('.uniform').attr('data-wrestler');

console.log('WTF: '+wtf);
console.log('WTF: '+JSON.stringify(wtf));
```

```html
<div id="foxtrott">
  foxtrott
  <div class="uniform" data-wrestler="hulkster">
    uniform
    <div class="charlie">
      charlie
      <div class="kilo">
        kilo
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you also have useful links to read about this topic this would be very nice.

Thanks in advance, guys !!!

Comment: How are you using this? It isn't clear.

Comment: yes, sorry! i update my question in a minute

Comment: Why do you have ``x.value;`` ? It is a separate statement, so you'd better write it on a separate line.

Comment: because `x = [x[0].getAttribute(s)].value;` didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return `x` instead of `this` in the `attr` method

```js
var $ = function(selector){

  var x; 
  var obj = {
  
    myLib(selector){
      return x || document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    },
    
    cl(selector){
      x = [x[0].closest(selector)];
      return this;
    },    
      
    attr(s,v){
      s&&v ? x.forEach(y=>{y.setAttribute(s,v);})
           : x = [x[0].getAttribute(s)]; 
      return x;
    },
      
  };
        
  x = obj.myLib(selector);
  return obj;
  
};

var wtf = $('.kilo').cl('.uniform').attr('data-wrestler');

console.log('WTF: '+wtf);
console.log('WTF: '+JSON.stringify(wtf));
```

```html
<div id="foxtrott">
  foxtrott
  <div class="uniform" data-wrestler="hulkster">
    uniform
    <div class="charlie">
      charlie
      <div class="kilo">
        kilo
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then you'd loose the chaining at `attr` setting. Make it return the string only when it is getting it, returning this otherwise.